# Долго загружается страница в WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Ребят выручайте. С Wordpress сильно незнаком, но есть проблема. Есть [сайт](https://viator.kz/). Когда его открываешь он очень долго грузит, а потом сразу показывается вся страница. Т.е. такое ощущение что он не показывает страницу, стоит какой то таймер, а после того как вся страница загружена он ее просто показывает. Как убрать эту паузу. Хочу что бы открывалась страница как обычно.

**UPD**
Основная загрузка страницы

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="mainpage">
    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>

<style>.async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} </style>
<script>(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
(a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
})(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
{'GTM-54WD4QZ':true});</script>


<!-- Rating@Mail.ru counter -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _tmr = window._tmr || (window._tmr = []);
_tmr.push({id: "2927266", type: "pageView", start: (new Date()).getTime()});
(function (d, w, id) {
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  var ts = d.createElement("script"); ts.type = "text/javascript"; ts.async = true; ts.id = id;
  ts.src = (d.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//top-fwz1.mail.ru/js/code.js";
  var f = function () {var s = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ts, s);};
  if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") { d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false); } else { f(); }
})(document, window, "topmailru-code");
</script><noscript><div>
<img src="//top-fwz1.mail.ru/counter?id=2927266;js=na" style="border:0;position:absolute;left:-9999px;" alt="" />
</div></noscript>
<!-- //Rating@Mail.ru counter -->
```

Удаляю все оставляю только это

1

так же долго грузит. Вывод что проблема в header. Ок делаю так,

    1

Все ровно долго грузит. Если убираю все и ставлю только вывод 1

```
1
```

Выводится мнгновенно. Вот и в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Наверное потому что стоит прелоадер, подозреваю что это облака в `.parallax-mirror`. P.S. верните сайт на место))

Comment: Сайт супер :) Отключаем js и видим мгновенную загрузку...пустой страницы!

Comment: @DaemonHK а где их найти?)))

Comment: @duddeniska, я не уверен, что это из-за них, всего лишь предположил. А вообще они самые первые идут, где они там в коде спрятаны, я не знаю

Comment: @DaemonHK Обновил ответ посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Visman обновил ответ, если только все грохнуть то тогда норм загружается

Answer (score 3):

У вас проблемы Javascript и CSS уменьшите их вес. Для СSS

```
 <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/green.css' rel='stylesheet' title='Color' >");
        $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/owl.carousel.css' rel='stylesheet' >");
        $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/owl.transitions.css' rel='stylesheet' >");
        $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/animate.min.css' rel='stylesheet' >");
        $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/fonts/fontello.css' rel='stylesheet' />");
    });
</script>
```

Для javascript :

```
<script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js" async></script>
```

Или пользуйтесь проффесиональными инструментами, на подобии gulp и bower.
Кроме того у вас боьшие проблемы с графикой:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fviator.kz%2Fall-visas%2F

Comment: Обновил ответ посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Это wp, тут запаришься оптимизировать

Comment: Картинки, основаня проблема

Comment: Проблема в графике, если сервер нормальный, можно поставить плагин и сжать.

Comment: В остальном, если вы программист, можете написать свой плагин оптимизации.

Answer (score 1):

Задержку уже убрали, насколько я вижу. Полагаю, что этот эффект давал некий прелоадер.

Есть много факторов других факторов, влияющих на скорость загрузки.

[Время ответа сервера](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fviator.kz%2F&tab=desktop) 1.3 секунды - это совсем плохо. Переезжайте на VPS.

Проблемы с картинками (как справедливо было отмечено в другом ответе). Чтобы удовлетворить требованиям Google PageSpeed Insights, картинки должны быть сжаты в Photoshop для web в jpeg с качеством 50%. И иметь размер не больше, чем реально отображаемый на экране.

Для сжатия и объединения файлов скриптов и стилей используйте плагин [Autoptimize](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/).

Кеширование страниц тоже резко сокращает время отклика. Плагин [WP Super Cache](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) сохраняет html-образы страниц, так что повторное выполнение кода php на сайте уже не нужно.

Перечисленные меры существенно сократят время отклика. Но начинать надо с главного - с хорошего сервера на VPS.

Comment: Autoptimize.и тп - фтопку :) От них толку нет, зато проблем хватает. (я же говорю - этот предмет порождает много споров и [ошибочных] мнений :)

Comment: Не согласен совершенно. Autoptimize + WP Super Cache очень даже помогают. Да, править сайт сложно - надо отключать, править, включать. Но отдача страниц существенно ускоряется.

Comment: Приходи на оф. форум ВП и поотвечай юзерам хотя бы с годик - узнаешь много нового, как оно У НИХ в реальности :)

Comment: @SeVlad Ну а то я своих юзеров не вижу.

Comment: Одно дело когда ТЫ им делаешь, и другое когда они не понимая что к чему слушают такие вот советы. Все равно что хирург будет советовать домохозяйкам скальпели для домашней операции на брюшине. А что конкретно до  минификации - от неё небольшой толк только в очень кривых сайтах. И то этот мнимый плюс меркнет перед другими проблемами. В тч и возможностью получить помощь на форумах.