# Оптимизировать сайт на WP + WC

Tags: wordpress

Проект на wp + wc, так же стоит плагин wpml. Метрика google speed page (на нем будет проверка) показывала результаты 13/37 (мобайл и десктоп соответственно) + там еще страница (homepage) на немецком, которая дает 9/27 !!!(там есть слайдер, без которого нельзя).

.htaccess  прописал модули mod_deflate b все остальные как положено, это немного на пару единиц улучшило ситуацию.

Ставил всевозможные плагины для оптимизации, сжатия (Autoptimize, super cache...), но ситуация немного разрядил только W3 total cache. Сейчас 22/54 нанемецком и на нашем 34/72 ! а нужно 80+ везде.... Какие мысли у вас есть по этому поводу?

Comment: Есть мысли что вопрос не для СО. На него нет однозначного ответа, а только мнения (ошибочные в тч. Кеш-лланины тому подтверждение). Зато в интернете есть  методики поиска источника проблем. Важно!! - методика, а не рецепты.

Comment: @SeVlad , вопрос  в том как увеличить скорость загрузки. Результат проверяется по google spped page. Перепробовал множество методик и разных вариантов приемлемых для данной ситуации. Один из вариантов улучшения стал W3 total cache. О чем я и написал. Я спрашиваю у сообщества КАК мне еще поднять показатели до 80+ исключительно для wp-проекта

Comment: 1. Тот гуглофейк не показывает СКОРОСТЬ. Никакую Ни загрузки ни выгрузки. Скорость и др проблемные  места показывают другие сервисы. 2. Ещё раз - на этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Более того - порождает много споров. Это не по правилам SO. Вот если бы ты спросил "какие есть методы поиска проблем" - это уже другой вопрос. И я не так давно  о них тут писал.

Comment: Вот мой ответ на похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/749015/220220

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оптимизация сайта на Wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743821/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Comment: А вот очень подробный ответ по оптимизации сайта на WordPress https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743906/220220 с картинкой реального сайта - 91/100 по PageSpeed

Comment: @SeVlad ну, во-первых, не совсем фейк. Если с умом подходить к этим рекомендациям, и применять то, что возможно применить, скорость загрузки возрастает. Во-вторых, можно по-разному относиться к PageSpeed Insights, но встречались заказчики, которые его хотят. Тут уж некуда деваться, приходилось повышать оценки.

Comment: @KAGGDesign совсем фейк. Начиная с самого названия. Но лениво и неудобно на СО это обсуждать и в 100й раз показывать и рассказывать. Я на сёрче и оф. форуме ВП  много раз показывал и объяснял.

Comment: @Александр по ссылке выше есть мой ответ. Изучи материалы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743885

Comment: @SeVlad, да, я как раз занимаюсь изучением материалов